# Paypal fee applicable to all calls or just a particular set of apis

Tags: paypal

Does the paypal fee applicable to any call within their apis or a particular call?

For instance, if I use any call within the /billing-agreements apis, do I get charged the 2.9% or less, plus $0.30 per transaction?

If not, which api do I use that charges me?

In the case, it only charges me a particular api, does that mean all other apis are free to use? how many calls can I make per day/month/year?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

PayPal will only charge you on successful transaction, Meaning they will not charge you for setting up a billing agreements nor for looking up a transaction with API, They will only charge you when the transaction of that billing agreement go through.

They are not charging the API call directly.

I coundn't find anything on limits in the documentation and as far as I know you can do an unlimited number of API call to paypal
Check the following link for PayPal documentation
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

### EDIT After Comment

Im not exactly sure how it works.
But I think PayPal system is somewhat queued based, In the sense that some API call are for creating subscription, They wont charge on the API call, But they will charge on every transaction recurring every month.. You don't need to make a API call every month to make the charge go through,
but still you'll see charges on your account.

Some call like [create_payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create) will have a response with "Successful"
But only after you also called [payment_execute](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_execute) but wont tell you what `transaction_fee` you had.

To get what `transaction_fee` you had You need to call with an other API call after to get that information
[payment_get](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_get)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know which exact api call that would respond as a successful transaction response? When you say they are not charging the api call directly, I would disagree, I would think they would charge on an API call that does the transaction when it's successful. No? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @MichaelYang Take a look at my edit,  Hope it helps :)